# Stopping a thread from another thread in a hashmap using a volatile boolean flag in java

Tags: java, multithreading

So i have my MainThread class that is responsible for all other threads.(creating, stopping, monitoring)

```
 public class MainThread implements Runnable {
      public static volatile boolean keepRunning = true;  

      public void run(){


      //some code..


      while(keepRunning){

      //here i am creating threads for my Wired class (explaining below) 
      //that are stored in a hashmap

      Wired wiredInterface = new Wired(s,defaultSleepTime,c,max,percent);
      Thread t1 = new Thread(wiredInterface);
      t1.start();
      }
```

far down in my code there is a case where i need to stop the thread t1.

My Wired Class:

```
   public class Wired implements Runnable {
        private static volatile boolean keepRunning = true;

        public void run(){

        while(keepRunning){

        //code

        try{
            Thread.sleep(((k - i + 1)*defaultTime) - DT);  //just to show that this thread sleeps periodically. doesnt affect the question
        }catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}  

        }
        }
```

In my Wired class i have this method for changing the volatile flag.

```
        public static void stopRunning(){
            keepRunning = false;
        }
```

My Question is..how can i access the method stopRunning from my MainThread for the specific thread that i want to stop? Thread.interrupt() doesnt work for me as a solution.

I have looked at a lot of similar questions referring to this subject but i havent found something suitable for my case. Sorry if i missed something 
This code is an oversimplification of my actual code

Comment: Please elaborate why would `interrupt` not work. If anything, it can only work **better** than your DYI mechanism.

Comment: You made it static, so it's just Wired.stopRunning() and it will apply to all of the threads.  Do not think this is what you intended?

Comment: interrupt doesn't work for you because you don't check for the interrupted flag, and ignore InterruptedExceptions. Use `while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())`, and also stop your loop as soon as you get an InterruptedException.

Comment: @Affe i made it static because at the end of the app all my threads will be stopped with a shutdownHook. You are right in the case i want only one thread to stop, static wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel here.  Use Thread.interrupt(), and properly check the Thread.isInterrupted() flag, and/or properly handle InterruptedException.  IE don't swallow it or printStackTrace() it and continue.  If you receive an InterruptedException catch it at the borders of the Runanble.run() method and stop your outer loop and shutdown the thread.

Your method should be changed to this:

```
public void run() {
   try {
      while( !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() ) {
          doSomeThreadedThing();
      }
   } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
      // maybe log some info you are shutting down
   }
}
```

It's really simple to properly shutdown a thread provided it isn't stuck in some IO.  If you have a long running task that you don't want to wait for check Thread.isInterrupted() within your logic periodically.  There are no advantages provided by your volatile boolean flag mechanism you have shown over using Thread.interrupted().

Comment: Is it ok if it receives the interrupt signal while sleeping? thanks for the answer, it does look better even though they asked us to use a  volatile flag

Comment: Actually, that's precisely why interrupt is better than a volatile variable. Interrupting a sleeping thread will make is go out of its sleeping state immediately and throw an InterruptedException, allowing to stop the thread immediately. Setting a volatile flag won't have any effect until the sleeping time is elapsed, and the thread will thus only stop after 2 hours if he sleeps for 2 hours. Same for almost all blocking methods (`wait()`, `lock()`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You should make keepRunning a instance variable (attribute) instead of static.

Whenever you want stop a Thread, grab it from Map and set the attribute keepRunning to false using setKeepRunning(false).